# R - Constrained optimization for a function taking a matrix

Tags: r, optimization, matrix

I would like to do constrained optimization for a function which takes a matrix as input. The matrix is sparse, representing a weighted adjacency matrix , and only the weights shall be subject to optimization.

An example matrix:

```
> AM
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.14    0 0.00
 [2,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.58 0.15 0.85 0.82    0 0.00
 [3,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.71 0.92 0.60    0 0.00
 [4,] 0.00 0.00 0.99 0.00 0.00 0.53 0.00    0 0.00
 [5,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.89 0.43    0 0.00
 [6,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00    0 0.98
 [7,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00    0 0.02
 [8,] 0.25 0.58 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00    0 0.00
 [9,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00    0 0.00
```

My function

```
H <- function(AM) {
  n <- dim(AM)[1]
  Pin<-colSums(AM)[1:(n-2)]
  Pout<-rowSums(AM)[1:(n-2)]
  H<-0
  for (i in 1:(n-2)) {
    for (j in 1:(n-2)) {
      if (AM[i,j]>0) {
        H <- H - AM[i,j]/sum(AM)*log(AM[i,j]/sum(AM))
      }
    }
  }
  return(H)
}
```

The output for the given matrix:

```
> H(AM)
[1] 2.107764
```

What I would like to do is to maximize H(AM), given the position of non-zero entries in AM (zero-entries in AM shall not be changed) and a few other constraints, namely:

```
rowSums(AM)[n-1] == c
colSums(AM)[1:(n-2)] == rowSums(AM)[1:(n-2)]
```

The optimization process should ideally work for any kind of matrix input (so that I don't have to specify the position or even number of non-zero entries manually).

I hope this problem is specified well enough, otherwise please let me know! Any help is very much appreciated!!

Many thanks!

PS: I also asked this question on stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394327/r-constrained-optimization-for-a-function-taking-a-matrix) but was referred to this platform.

Comment: Is there any constraints on `AM`, e.g. should AM* be PSD?

Comment: AM should have only positive entries and is limited to describing acyclic graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an outline of a solution.  The trick is to make a function
that that takes a vector with length equal to the number of non-zero
entries in your matrix (`AM`) and returns a matrix with the appropriate 
format.

Here's an example of you you can create functions that will do just that
given an initial value of your matrix `AM`:

```
# a factor function which returns functions that build 
# matrices with non-zeros in the same entries as the
# argument `AM` 
AM_builder_Factory <- function(AM,c){
    force(c)
    DIM <- dim(AM)
    nonZeros <- which(as.vector(AM)>0)

    # this inner function will be the return value of 
    # AM_builder_Factory
    function(x){
        out<-numeric(prod(DIM))
        # Here I'm using the  exponential transformation so that the 
        # non-zero entries in the output matrix are all positive.
        # Many other transformations are possible, and may be more
        # efficient depending on the function H() being optimized.
        out[nonZeros] <- exp(x)

        # Here is where you'll have to implement these constraints
        # rowSums(AM)[n-1] == c
        # colSums(AM)[1:(n-2)] == rowSums(AM)[1:(n-2)]

        dim(out) <- DIM
        out
    }
}

# the function 'AM_builder' takes a vector with
# numeric values and returns a matrix with the shape
# of the initial AM, and with zero and non-zero values 
# in the same locations as AM
AM_builder <- AM_builder_Factory(AM)

# for example,
AM = matrix(c(1,0,0,
              2,3,0,
              0,4,5),nrow=3,byrow=T)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    0    0
#> [2,]    2    3    0
#> [3,]    0    4    5

builder <- AM_builder_Factory(AM)
builder(log(5:1))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    5    0    0
#> [2,]    4    3    0
#> [3,]    0    2    1
```

Now that you have a function `builder` that builds your matrices, you 
can use one of the optimization functions like `nlm` to optimize your function `H()`

```
# we need a set of starting parameters, which we'll take as the log
# of the non-zero values in `AM`.  [We're using log() of the non-zero 
# values in AM because log() is he inverse of exp() which is used in 
# the builder function to convert numeric values to positive values.]
start<- as.vector(AM)
start <- start[start>0]
val = nlm(f=function(x) - H(builder(x)), #  the function to be minimized
          p=log(start)) # starting parameter values for the minimization 

# the minimum value of H conditional on the format of AM
- val$minimum

# the optimized matrix 
builder(val$estimate)
```

Note that the inner function inner function of `AM_builder_Factory` is not trivial b/c there are multiple ways to implement your constraints, and the constraints will necessarily reduce the number of independent (non-zero) entries in AM, so you'll have to adjust the definition the inner function to take a an argument (x) with length less than the number of non-zero entries in AM.

Comment: Thank you so much Jthorpe, this was very very helpful! Actually I had been quite close already, but your answer helped me to finish up the task. Thank you so much for your quick, comprehensive and uttermost helpful post!

Comment: Very helpful indeed! I like the factory function approach!